# Load Function After Page Load

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

How do I want to call a `popupwindow` function after a page is load. Below are my code on `index.php` page.

```
function ajaxLoad(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var page = $(this).attr('href'); //search.php 
    $('.result-search').load(page, function(){
        $(".popupwindow").popupwindow();
    });
}

$(document).on("click",".search-link", ajaxLoad);
```

My code does not call the function. On my `search.php` page, I have a link to view document details.

```
<?php echo '<a href="uploads/' . $dokumen . '" target="_blank" class="popupwindow">open</a>'; ?>
```

When user click on the link, I want it to open on a new pop up window. Do I have to make a separate popupwindow function on my `search.php` page? I thought I can call the function on my `index.php` page like I did above.

Comment: The link doesn't have `class="seach-link"`

Comment: The search-link class is on my index.php page. When user click, it will go to search.php page. On my search.php page, there is another link that I want it to open on a new window. In this condition, do I have to use same class also?

Comment: @Barmar is it ok if I put the function on my search.php page. Will it effect the page performance in terms of speed or loading page?

Comment: Are you trying to use Javascript on `index.php` to do something on `search.php`? That won't work.